# Framer.js generator - is it working?

Tags: framerjs

I'm using the framer generator (v 3.0.33 (37)) to import something from Sketch Beta (v 3.0.4 (8156)). The import is successful, but when I open the .framer folder that is created I get the following message in framer studio:

```
# I could not find an app.coffee file in your project so an empty one was created.

# If you worked in javascript before you can translate your app.js file to coffee script at: http://js2coffee.org/
```

Should the generator create the app.coffee file for me? As it stands now, all framer generator is doing is creating .png files that I need to manually add to another framer project that has an app.coffee file. I'm a new user of the application, but it seems that either it's not working, I'm not using it right, or it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Works in Framer Studio v1.0.181.  app.coffee file is present upon import.